# postgres update with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update table tr with data from ht. Both have almost same columns.
So to test I ran the this query.

```
SELECT * FROM tr a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ht b
USING (date, name, ft )
WHERE ft IS NOT NULL
```

Gives 129 rows
Check it was ok, then I ran the update query as->

```
UPDATE tr
SET (o_t, g_v, br, s_t, st, c_d, n_r, n_a, cd_id) 
    = (a.o_t, a.g_v, a.br, a.s_t, a.st, a.c_d, a.n_r, a.n_a, 
    a.cd_id)
FROM tr a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ht b
USING (date, name, ft )
WHERE a.ft IS NOT NULL
```

Query returned successfully: 4134 rows affected

Can some on guide me what went wrong and how to go about it.

Comment: You have right outer join on first, left outer join on second. That might have something to do with it?

Comment: corrected the sql. Problem is with this one only

Comment: It's more robust to just paste in the code that you're using, otherwise you're inviting all kinds of typos that look like the problem but are not.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  Either a single row matches and hence the values do not change.  Do you intend for the values to come from `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit complicated in Postgres.  However, I question your logic.  It would seem that a `right outer join` is not correct, because you are checking that the first table is not `NULL`.  So this would *seem* to capture your logic:

```
UPDATE tr
SET (o_t, g_v, br, s_t, st, c_d, n_r, n_a, cd_id) 
    = (a.o_t, a.g_v, a.br, a.s_t, a.st, a.c_d, a.n_r, a.n_a, 
    a.cd_id)
FROM tr a JOIN
     ht b
     USING (date, name, ft );
```

The `where` clause is even redundant, because the value cannot be `NULL` due to the `join` condition.  In any case, this doesn't work, but it does point to the right solution.

In Postgres, the table in the `update` cannot be in the `FROM` clause, unless your intention is a self join.  So, try this version:

```
UPDATE tr
SET (o_t, g_v, br, s_t, st, c_d, n_r, n_a, cd_id) 
    = (a.o_t, a.g_v, a.br, a.s_t, a.st, a.c_d, a.n_r, a.n_a, 
    a.cd_id)
FROM tr a JOIN
     ht b
     USING (date, name, ft )
WHERE tr.date = a.date and tr.name = a.name and tr.ft = a.ft;
```

However, this update doesn't make sense.  I suspect that you want the values to come from `ht`, *NOT* `tr`, when there is a match.  If so, this is the simplest way:

```
UPDATE tr
    SET (o_t, g_v, br, s_t, st, c_d, n_r, n_a, cd_id) 
        = (a.o_t, a.g_v, a.br, a.s_t, a.st, a.c_d, a.n_r, a.n_a, 
        a.cd_id)
    FROM ht a
    WHERE tr.date = a.date and tr.name = a.name and tr.ft = a.ft;
```